# get client IP address for each request in mule

Tags: wsdl, cxf, mule, callable

I launched a wsdl with cxf services in mule. I passed client Ip address as a variable to java class in xml mule config. 
I implemented a callable class for getting Ip address and inserting ip in database. 
For testing, I created a web service with wsdl of mule. 
in duration of this procedure, just when I created class of wsdl, client Ip inserted in database. 
Unfortunately, when I used web service and I sent requests, no IP inserted in database. 
My goal: I want to insert client Ip into database after every request.

I use Mule 3.3.0 CE. and my code is bellow:

```
<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.3.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/3.3/mule-spring-security.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd ">

<global-property name="allowed" value="192.168.3.76,192.168.3.74,192.168.3.75" />

<configuration>
    <expression-language>
        <global-functions>
            def parseIp(fullIp) {
            return fullIp.substring(fullIp.indexOf('/') + 1, fullIp.indexOf(':'))
            }
        </global-functions>
    </expression-language>
</configuration>

<http:connector name="httpConnector" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
    <service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler" />
</http:connector>

<mule-ss:security-manager>
    <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider
        name="memory-dao" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
</mule-ss:security-manager>
<spring:beans>
    <ss:authentication-manager
        xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" alias="authenticationManager">
        <ss:authentication-provider>
            <ss:user-service id="userService">
                <ss:user name="weather" password="weather" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </ss:user-service>
        </ss:authentication-provider>
    </ss:authentication-manager>
</spring:beans>

<flow name="Weather" doc:name="Weather">
    <http:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="9091"
        path="/web-service/weather" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP">
    <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm" />
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <expression-filter
        expression="#['${allowed}'.contains(parseIp(message.inboundProperties['MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS']))]"
        doc:name="Expression" />

    <set-variable variableName="remoteClientAddress"
        value="#[parseIp(message.inboundProperties['MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS'])]" />
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="myproperty"
        scope="session">
        <add-message-property key="message.payload.remoteClientAddress"
            value="#[parseIp(message.inboundProperties['MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS'])]" />
    </message-properties-transformer>

    <component doc:name="classTest" class="org.mule.example.scripting.IpClient" />      

    <cxf:proxy-service 
        service="Weather"
        wsdlLocation="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl"
        namespace="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/"
        validationEnabled="true" doc:name="SOAP">
    </cxf:proxy-service>

    <copy-properties propertyName="SOAPAction" doc:name="Property" />

    <cxf:proxy-client doc:name="SOAP" />

    <outbound-endpoint 
        address="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx"
        exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="Generic">
    </outbound-endpoint>

</flow>
```

and my java class:

```
public class IpClient  implements Callable {

  @Override
  public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {

  MuleMessage msg = eventContext.getMessage();

String remClient = msg.getProperty("remoteClientAddress", PropertyScope.INVOCATION);

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();

ConnectDB c = new ConnectDB("localhost:3306", "report", "root", "123456");

String sql = " INSERT INTO oml_news (ip, date) VALUES (?,?) ";

PreparedStatement ps = c.getConnnection().prepareStatement(sql);

ps.setString(1, remClient);

ps.setString(2, dateFormat.format(date).toString());

  ps.executeUpdate();

  c.close();

  return true;

  }
```

Comment: Q: Does your Java function ever get called?  Q: If not, why not?  Q: What debugging/logging tools do you have available?  What debugging steps have you tried?

Comment: Yes @paulsm4, my java function ever gets called. I just use mule studio. and I use soapui pro for testing again. Can you explain more?

Comment: Have you debugged to see the value of remClient inside the Java component?

Comment: Suggestion (not related to your question): use `set-session-variable` instead of `message-properties-transformer` to set a session variable.

Comment: Why don't you use a JDBC outbound endpoint? Why a custom class for such a simple query?

Comment: Also I notice you return `true` from the component: isn't this value messing up your outbound call? `true` becomes the new payload...

Comment: @Seba, I can see remClient inside the java component.

Comment: @DavidDossot, I used JDBC outbound endpoint before, but I wanted to add some features to my project that I couldn't define in xml config. so I used custom class.

Comment: @DavidDossot, I don't wnat to return variable to xml config, I just save my variable value in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're problem is most certainly due to the fact that you're not sending the SOAP request to the Mule service.

Check how the endpoint URL in SOAPui.

Comment: my url in SoapUI is [link](http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx) instead of mule url (http://localhost:9091/web-service/weather).